# Return Ajax data on Index() in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Index() which return empty view() like below

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And GetDashboardSummaryData() which accept int parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult GetDashboardSummaryData(int year)
{
  ContentResult json = new ContentResult();
  json.Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dashboardSummaryListViewModels);
  json.ContentType = "application/json";
  json.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  return json;

}
```

On my cshtml page

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    year = new Date().getFullYear();
    GetDashboardSummaryData(year);
 });

function GetDashboardSummaryData(year) {
    var url = "@Url.Content("~/Dashboard/GetDashboardSummaryData")";
    url = url + "?year=" + year;
    $.ajax
      ({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          success: function (data) {
            //Populating chart data using data
        });

}
```

Above all functionality is working as expected but when I debug my code first it goes to the Index() which basically return empty view and on document.ready event it again does AJAX call to fetch data from server side.

Is it possible that retrieve data for the current year on page load event(i.e. in Index()) itself instead of another separate ajax call to get initial data.

Comment: Why are't you using `Url.Action` and `JsonResult`?

Comment: @Satpal there is no specific reason I did use ContentResult, I can replace it with JsonResult

Comment: Change your parameter name **year** to **id** in `GetDashboardSummaryData()` method. This is because of `default Route`. Then change in that method **ContentResult** to **JsonResult**. And your `URL` should be like this in your Ajax call, `"../Dashboard/GetDashboardSummaryData/"+year;`

Comment: You could also add a route with the new parameter instead.  It certainly makes it clearer.

Comment: You could just put the JSON for the current year in a string variable and pass it in your document.ready to fill your chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Url.Action()` in your javascript code then use `JsonResult` return type with controller action like following.

**//javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    year = new Date().getFullYear();
    GetDashboardSummaryData(year);
});

function GetDashboardSummaryData(year) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetDashboardSummaryData","Dashboard")';
    url = url + "/" + year;
    $.ajax
      ({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        });

}
```

**//controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDashboardSummaryData(int? year)
{
  var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dashboardSummaryListViewModels);
  val year = year;
  return return Json(new {model = result , year = year});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this issue.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(GetDashboardSummaryData(DateTime.Today.Year));
}
```

Here is my GetDashboardSummaryData()

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDashboardSummaryData(int year)
{
  return Json(dashboardSummaryListViewModels, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

cshtml page

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Data));
    PopulateChart(data);
 });
```